# How do I create a WordPress query that filters out multiple authors?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, join

I’ve been trying to do a WordPress query and have hit quite a major snag. Here’s the how I want to query the posts:

```
<?php query_posts( 's=@' . $user_login . '&author=-4,-5,-6&posts_per_page=25&paged='. $paged ); ?>
```

As you can see from this code, I’m attempting to exclude authors with the id’s of 4, 5, and 6. However, WordPress does not currently allow this functionality (as it does with categories).

Does anyone have any ideas how I can accomplish this goal—maybe a custom query/join? Any help would be much, much appreciated!

Comment: Added note: Everything works EXCEPT the &author= portion of the query. That's really the only portion of the code I'm hoping to find a workaround for. Thanks!

Comment: Please check my answer. Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress currently doesn't support removing multiple author posts from the query at a time.

But we can make use of another hook `posts_where` to remove the authors we do not need. But if we use this hook it will affect all the places in WordPress. So we should be careful when hooking this filter.

If you add it in the `functions.php` file it will run throughout all the queries which have `post_where` hook.

Add this function in your `functions.php` of the theme.

```
function remove_author_posts ($where) {
    global $wpdb; 

    //add the author id's you need to remove
    $removed_authors   = array ('4', '5', '6');

    $where .= ' AND ' .  $wpdb->posts . '.post_author !=' . implode(' AND ' .  $wpdb->posts . '.post_author !=', $removed_authors);
    return $where;
}
```

Now add this filter to the place where you are calling the query_posts

```
add_filter ('posts_where', 'remove_author_posts');
```

Don't add this filter hook in your themes `functions.php` file. Only add in the place you need.

Now change your query posts and add the filter in the page you need like this:

```
query_posts( 's=' . $user_login . '&posts_per_page=25&paged='. $paged );
```

So the complete thing will look like

```
add_filter ('posts_where', 'remove_author_posts');
query_posts( 's=' . $user_login . '&posts_per_page=25&paged='. $paged );
```

**UPDATE :**

You can use `global` variable if you need to change the author id's dynamically. Add a new `global` variable `$remove_authors` before you add the filter.

```
global $removed_authors ;
//add the author id's you need to remove
$removed_authors   = array ('4', '5', '6');

add_filter ('posts_where', 'remove_author_posts');
query_posts( 's=' . $user_login . '&posts_per_page=25&paged='. $paged );
```

Now change the remove_author_posts in functions.php file

```
function remove_author_posts ($where) {

    global $wpdb, $removed_authors;

    if (empty ($removed_authors) || !is_array($removed_authors))
        return $where;

    $where .= ' AND ' .  $wpdb->posts . '.post_author !=' . implode(' AND ' .  $wpdb->posts . '.post_author !=', $removed_authors);

    return $where;
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent answer and really helps. Would there be away to easily determine a variable number of authors? For example, it may be users 5,6,7 at one time, but needs to be flexible enough to change to users 8,9 at another time. Is this possible? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php query_posts( 's=@' . $user_login . 'author=-4,-5,-6' '&posts_per_page=25' . '&paged='. $paged );
```

to

```
<?php query_posts( 's=' . $user_login . '&author=-4&author=-5&author=-6&posts_per_page=25&paged='. $paged );
```

To elimate multiple author call as

> author=-4&author=-6 .... so on

Reference: http://www.yoursearchbuddy.com/wordpress-show-post-exclude-author

Comment: Oops, my bad, forgot that in my code. Still doesn't work even with the &, or minus the @ in the search portion of the query, unfortunately.

Comment: checked  $user_login and $paged value passed

Comment: $user_login = wp_get_current_user(); $user_login = $user_login->user_login;

Comment: Everything in the query works fine apart from &author=-4,-5,-6. That's really the only part I need a workaround for.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Applying multiple authors with &author=-5&author=-6 will only filter out id 6. The 5 id is ignored and still shows up in the list of posts.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but for the benefit of any googlers, you can now do this in a much nicer way with `WP_Query`, as of WordPress v3.7: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

*You can also exclude multiple authors this way:*

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__not_in' => array( 4, 5, 6 ) ) );
```